# symfony2.8 @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks() is not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, entity

I found @ORM\PrePersist is not work in my project,I want to dump a number before persist then die the procedure，but the problem is "$em->persist();" still execute，and the number did not dump, here is my demo:

```
<?php

namespace Nlc\InformationBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */

class Adminuser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function test(){
        dump(1);die;
    }
}



<?php

namespace Nlc\InformationBundle\Controller;


use Nlc\InformationBundle\Entity\Adminuser;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AdminuserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/testadmin")
     */
    public function testadmin(){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $adminuser = new Adminuser();
        $adminuser->setUsername('dave');
        $adminuser->setPassword('123');
        //before persist,I want dump 1 then die,but did't work
        $em->persist($adminuser);
        $em->flush();
        return new Response();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any properties because I can't see it in this example but I see you have some setters?

Comment: I want to execute the test() function and dump 1, but it's not work, do you know why?

Comment: I think the reason is that you don't have any properties so doctrine don't want to do any persistance.

Comment: I tried, still not work

Comment: Maybe you should try clear your doctrine cache: php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata

Comment: It works for me. Can you give us some more details? What doctrine version do you have? Is your database MySql, or Sqlite...

Comment: my doctrine version is  "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8", and my database is Mysql
I clear the cache, It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you try to add just an id or something like that maybe Doctrine will try to persist your entity.

```
<?php

namespace Nlc\InformationBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */

class Adminuser
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function test(){
        dump(1);die;
    }
}
```